# Retrieve Heroku logs programmatically

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

I want to be able to access the Heroku-provided logs for my Node.js app online. Is there a way to add this into my app, or to use some REST API with AJAX for this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Heroku Platform API to start a log session: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#log-session

There's a Node.js wrapper for the Heroku API here: https://github.com/heroku/node-heroku-client